# VideoJS 'Video error'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video.js

I have a simple view that I'm using to test out video.js; it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/video.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
</script>
<body>
    <video id="testPlayer" class="video-js" controls preload="auto"  
        poster="~/Content/images/video-js.png"
        data-setup="{}">
        <source src="<url of a .mp4 file stored in my project>" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
```

After the page loads, I see the poster on the video player (along with some metadata information below the player that I haven't figured out how to get rid of yet). With `preload="auto"` I see `["Video Error", Object]` immediately on page load in the console (using Chrome). If I change `auto` to `none`, I get the same non-descript error when I click the player. I cannot figure out what the problem with this error.

There doesn't seem to be any information tucked in the object that shows in the console. The best I could find, as far as description, was something that said `media error`. I've tried messing around with the encoding of the file a few different ways, but I consistently get the same error.

Does anyone see anything wrong with the view that I am missing (or know what in the world this error could mean)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying my source URL I was specifying it like this:

```
src="~/Content/something/place/etc.mp4"
```

Upon changing that URL to

```
src='@Url.Content("~Content/you/get/the/point.mp4")'
```

The video loads fine. I stumbled on some post that mentioned the video tag needing an absolute path, and took a stab trying this.